# How to determine when threads are in a deadlock from Main C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, deadlock, dining-philosopher

I have read other posts about tools for deadlock detection and avoiding deadlock; but my question is specifically about how to find when threads are in deadlock from Main so that I can make the Main thread sleep until the threads are deadlocked and proceed further.

I tried to use ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin to detect whether all threads are deadlocked for a longer period of time in Main, but that doesn't seem like working; Are there any utility methods available to determine when all threads are deadlocked?

I am trying to implement deadlock scenario in Dining philosophers where when all the threads take either right or left chopstick first, they will wait for the other chopstick forever and hence deadlock occurs; only issue is that I am not able to find when all these threads enter into waiting state for ever from Main.

This is my Run method:

```
public virtual void Run()
    {
        while (!stop)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            try
            {
                outputList.Add("Thinking", identity);
                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 100000000));

                outputList.Add("Hungry", identity);
                right.get();
                outputList.Add("Got Right", identity);

                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 100000000));

                left.get();
                outputList.Add("Got Left", identity);
                outputList.Add("Eating", identity);

                Thread.Sleep(random.Next(1, 100000000));
                right.put();
                left.put();
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            { }
        }
    }
```

This is Main:

```
      public static List<DiningState> MainFunction(int numberPhilosophers)
      {
        Thread[] phil = new Thread[numberPhilosophers];
        ChopStick[] fork = new ChopStick[numberPhilosophers];
        DeadlockDiningPhilosopherController ph = null;

        for (int i = 0; i < numberPhilosophers; ++i)
        {
            fork[i] = new ChopStick(i);
        }

        Stopwatch time = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        for (int i = 0; i < numberPhilosophers; ++i)
        {
            ph = new DeadlockDiningPhilosopherController(i, fork[(i - 1 + numberPhilosophers) % numberPhilosophers], fork[i]);
            phil[i] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ph.Run));
            phil[i].Start();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < numberPhilosophers; i++)
        {
            if (phil[i].ThreadState != System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            {
                i = i - 1;
                Thread.Sleep(10000);
            }
            else
            {
                continue;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < numberPhilosophers; i++)
        {
            if (phil[i].ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.WaitSleepJoin)
            {
                phil[i].Abort();
            }
        }
        time.Stop();

        int timespan = (int)time.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
        Console.WriteLine("Total Time: " + time.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + time.Elapsed.TotalSeconds);

        return outputList;
     }
```

How can I replace the WaitSleepJoin with an efficient solution to find out when all threads are deadlocked?

Please help, any suggestions are greatly appreciated! thank you!

Comment: Well, in the general case you're talking about solving the Halting Problem, which is [famously] provably impossible.  You can really only kinda guess, and even then, it's generally best to write programs that you are sure can't deadlock than to try to detect it at runtime.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for you reply. If this is the case, I have seen animations of Dining philosopher where they show the deadlock scenario, where they show when the program enters deadlock state. How can I achieve that behavior? If any suggestions, please let me know!

Comment: Well, first off, it's a pretty trivial problem.  About as trivial as it gets with respect to deadlocks.  There are a *lot* of solutions, as it's literally the most common textbook example for how to generate, and consequently address, such issues.  Each person has their own take on how to make a working version.  Some try to detect the deadlock, others throw timeouts on how they hold the lock, still others alter the means of acquiring resources such that it becomes impossible to deadlock.  Generally speaking, I prefer the last approach.

Answer (score 0):

If a thread is deadlocked, I don't think you can make it work from main thrad. The only thing we can do is trying to avoid deadlock using lock, Mutex, Monitor, etc.

Comment: Thanks for you reply. If this is the case, I have seen animations of Dining philosopher where they show the deadlock scenario, where they show when the program enters deadlock state. How can I achieve that behavior? If any suggestions, please let me know!